# How to deform a 2d shape to make a 3d object?

Tags: modifiers

I have a 2d flat mesh that i would like to manipulate without any distortion to create a 3D shape. Typically for the pie below, joining the 2 edges together would make a 3D cone. Do you have any idea of which modifier to use ? [image] [image: Cone paper pattern]

Comment: I don't understand what result do you expect. Could you provide screenshot with something similar to your expectation?

Comment: Sorry it was not very clear :) I added an illustration on how we do this manipulation with a real piece of paper, hope it helps understanding

Comment: There is no modifier that magically turns 2D shapes into 3D objects. How should Blender know, what you are expecting the object to look like? Why don't you do it the other way round? Maybe you could add a little more information about what **exactly** you want achieve?

Comment: What i have been thinking is that if you constraint one of the edges not to move and the other being able to move towards it, then all the other vertices of the mesh would follow in such a way that the mesh faces would not be distorded. This will force the cone to take shape

Comment: I'm not sure constraints work on vertex groups. Perhaps a shape key or, possibly, a set of several shape keys. Rigging may work as well. Or pinning the centre vertex and using cloth sim to have the paper fall onto a cone with collision physics.

Comment: You can use  [proportional editing](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/proportional_edit.html) to make vertices follow your selection as you move it, but it still wouldn't make the shape 3D. It's not really clear what you want to achieve... Why do you want to make a cone from the flat shape when you can just simply add a cone to the scene and give it the size you want?

Comment: @Karolina Not being the OP, I can only guess, but how about animating paper folding. I agree with you that it would be fairly pointless to model a cone like this, but animating paper being wrapped into a conic shape, may very well serve a purpose. The purpose could be just about anything, e.g. learning how to do it in Blender, teaching how to do it in the real world or just for fun.

Comment: The proportional editing would distord my mesh, wouldn't it ? I am sorry i am fairly new to blender... Actually i am not interested in creating cones but the physic simulation behind this operation and if it could be done in blender. Would the armature modifier or the laplacian deform modifier be useful here ?

Comment: @Duane OK, I can see the point now :) But to do that animation, you'd still need both the dimensions of the flat piece of paper and the dimensions of the final cone. It seems easier to start from a cone and make it flat than to start from a flat piece.

Comment: An armature could absolutely work (and that's what I meant by rigging in one of my previous comments). But to make it realistic, care would have to be taken to retain the surface area of the paper as it gets transformed, as @Karolina points out. I'd need to crunch some numbers to get it working, and that part I can do, but I'm not that much into rigging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Managed to **approximate** this with *Shape Keys*, starting out with a cone, it's easier than starting out with a flat shape and bending it into your will.

[image: Cone Final]

1. Add a cone mesh with whatever final dimensions you want it to have
2. Move it in edit mode so it's center is on the center of the base (not mid height)
3. Erase the left part and the bottom face and then add a *Mirror* modifier

[image: Add Cone]

4. Add two new shape keys one is the base as it currently is, and another (Key 1) will be it's flat shape.
5. Now some math, in edit mode check the length of one of the cone large side edges with the *3D view > Properties Region > Mesh Display > Length* that will determine the radius of the final flat shape
6. Add a new mesh circle object, it's radius should be the length of the previously measured edge, and it the number radius vertices should be **1 1/4** the number of vertices of the cone. So if by default a cone has **32** vertex so the circle should have **1.25 x 32 = 40 vertices**.
7. Erase one quarter of the circle's edges so that they are centered around the edge you ripped in Step 3

[image: Circle]

8. Now with shape *Key 1* selected enter edit mode on the cone, move the central vertex down until it is flat
9. Scale all the vertex in the cone base so that they reach the circle radius (use snap for better precision)

[image: Flatten]

10. Press <kbd>.</kbd>(Period Key) to transform centered in *3D Cursor*
11. Hide all the cone vertex but the outer rim of the base, including the vertex at X=0
12. With *Proportional Edit* set to *Connected* and the *Fallof* type set to *Linear*, select only the lower vertex and rotate them all 1/8 of a turn, so they snap to the open end of the circle. Adjust the *Proportional Edit* radius with the mouse wheel.

[image: Rotate]

13.Profit! (Adjust progression with the shapekey *Value* Slider)

[image: Final resul]

You may then give it a more natural or organic looking transition with some modifiers or with manually bending the shape a little with more shapekeys

Answer (score 6):

Using a script to make the two shape keys.  Change the r and h of result cone.

[image]

*Example of radius 1, height 2, 1 and 0.5 cones.*

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector
from math import radians, sin, cos, sqrt

from bpy import context # for testing

r = 1 # radius of cone
h = 1 # height of cone
sectors = 16
l = sqrt(r**2 + h**2) # hypotenuse
# sector will have angle 

theta = radians(360) * r / l
dtheta = theta / sectors

# build the base

bm = bmesh.new()

verts = []
for i in range(sectors + 1):
    a = i * dtheta
    verts.append(bm.verts.new((l * cos(a), l * sin(a), 0)))

topvert = bm.verts.new((0, 0, 0))
for i in range(sectors):
    bm.faces.new([verts[i + 1], topvert, verts[i]])

cone_mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("Cone")
cone = bpy.data.objects.new("Cone", cone_mesh)         
bm.to_mesh(cone_mesh)


# add base as basis shape key
basis_shape_key = cone.shape_key_add("Basis")

# add second shape key

cone_shape_key = cone.shape_key_add("Cone")
offset = (radians(360) - theta) / 2
dtheta = radians(360) / sectors
for v in verts:
    a = v.index * dtheta - offset
    cone_shape_key.data[v.index].co = ((r * cos(a), r * sin(a), 0))
cone_shape_key.data[topvert.index].co = (0, 0, h)

# link to scene

scene = context.scene
scene.objects.link(cone)
scene.objects.active = cone
cone.select = True
```